# Passing ClientConnections around different processes

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

Have run into a slight problem regarding Client Connections that need to be passed between threads.

1.) We have a service class

```
    public class Service : ServiceBase
    {
        public ServiceHost serviceHost = null;

        public CMLiteService()
        {
            ServiceName = "MyService";
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(new Service());
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                if (serviceHost != null)
                {
                    serviceHost.Close();
                }

                Uri baseAddress = new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/Service");

                // Step 2 Create a ServiceHost instance
                serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), baseAddress);


                // Step 3 Add a service endpoint.
                serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "Service");

                serviceHost.Open();

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }

        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            if (serviceHost != null)
            {
                serviceHost.Close();
                serviceHost = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

2.) We have an interface

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string InitalizeDataStore(string uri1, string uri2);
        [OperationContract]
        string CheckHealth();
        [OperationContract]
        string CreateObject(string parameters);
    }
```

3.) We have a method that Initializes Our data storage

```
ObjectOperations objectOperations;
public InitalizeDataStore (string uri1, string uri2)
{
    Admin admin = new Admin(uri1, uri2);
    objectOperations = new ObjectOperations(admin.client1, admin.client2);
}
```

4.) Here is the admin class that does the actual connecting to the database, both there clients are thread safe and support multithreading

```
StorageClient1 client1
StorageClient2 client2
string URI1;
string URI2;

public AdminServices(string uri1, string uri2)
    {
        URI1 = uri1;
        URI2 = uri2;

        InitializeClient1();
        InitializeClient2();
    }

    public StorageClient1 InitializeClient1()
    {
        try
        {
            client1 = new Client(new Uri(URI1));
            client1.Connect();
            return client1;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public Client2 InitializeClient2()
    {
        try
        {
            client2 = new Client(new Uri(URI2));
            client2.Connect();
            return client2;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

5.) When we start the service and run the initialization method it connects and works. But when we start another process the client connections are null? If we run the code top down in one console app it works but we are in need of running initialization once and then the client connection must be set for future processes.

So Process 1:

```
IService pipeProxy = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
pipeProxy.InitalizeDataStore(); //Returns "Connected"

Process 2: 
IService pipeProxy = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
pipeProxy.CheckHealth(); //returns null
```

How do we insure that the Client Connection details are also made availible in another process. I am very new too this so Im not too clued up on multithreading.

Comment: Why would you expect these things to exist across processes? Processes do not share memory, as a rule. Why not just use separate threads within the same process?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are trying to accomplish is served by the WCF Singleton instance mode:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]
```

Attribute your implementing class with the above, and all clients will share an instance.

Comment: I have recently come across this attribute. Does that mean that if I request something and another person requests the same thing, that the other person will only receive the data only after I have been served. Does this method effect scale-ability?

Comment: Absolutely. Mind you, this solution is the one that requires the minimum amount of architecture changes in your existing code. If you were willing to make more changes, I would recommend sticking with the SingleCall instance mode (which is the default) and refactoring your existing code to have the service-side WCF classes share an internal instance of the Admin class (perhaps a static instance using the [Singleton pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) (which should not be confused with WCF's Singleton).